# Appending dictionary values to a list unexpectedly resulting in a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
name_dict = {'A':'1', 'B':'2','C':'3'}
```

I am trying to rename columns whose name (A, B, C) is in the dictionary using the following loop

```
newcols = []
for col in enhancer.columns:
    if col in name_dict:
        newcols.append(name_dict[col])  
    else:  
        newcols.append(col)
enhancer.columns = newcols
```

However instead of `newcols = ['1','2','3']` I am getting `newcols = [['1'], ['2'], ['3']]`

How can I avoid creating this list of lists so I am able to change the column names without getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`?

Comment: `enhancer = enhancer.rename(columns=name_dict)` or `enhancer.columns = enhancer.columns.replace(name_dict)`?

Comment: It appears that `enhancer.columns` consists of lists, not strings.  Fix that.

Comment: @QuangHoang that is giving me the same error. The issue seems to be with how I am creating the dictionary

Comment: Looks like your `name_dict` is `{'A':['1'],...}`

Comment: @QuangHoang you are correct. I am creating it in a previous loop using `name_dict[name_key].append(name)` any idea why this is happening? Or should I edit the question to include more info about creating the dict?

Comment: @keenan does the updated answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated based on comments] It would be helpful to see what `enhancer.columns` contains. I assume that it is something like:

```
class enhancer():
    columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

From the comments, it sounds like `name_dict` contains lists not strings. e.g.:

```
name_dict = {'A':['1'], 'B':['2'], 'C':['3']}
```

The result is that your output is a list of lists. A couple of straightforward fixes are:

1. change `name_dict` to a dictionary of strings (e.g. `{'A': '1', 'B':'2', 'C':'3'}`)
2. modify the loop. e.g.:

```py
name_dict = {'A':['1'], 'B':['2'], 'C':['3']}

class enhancer():
    columns = ["A", "B", "C"]

newcols = []
for col in enhancer.columns:
    if col in name_dict:
        # add the string to the list, rather than append
        newcols += name_dict[col]
    else:
        # add the string to the list, rather than append
        newcols += col

enhancer.columns = newcols

print(enhancer.columns)
```

which outputs:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```